# POST image using flutter

Tags: flutter, http-post, image-upload

I have some experience using POST and GET to a server for JSON, via Flutter, but this file business has me flummoxed.

The server code has a commandline structure format like:

```
curl --location --request POST 'URIaddress' \
--form 'data_id=001' \
--form 'image=@/file.jpg'
```

and I cannot imagine how this is compatible with the other multipart stream uploads I've seen for flutter.

The file is a temp filepath and filename for a jpg from Flutter's image_picker (_image).

If I make a call :

```
var val = API.updateImage(sampleID:sampleId),file: _image);
```

What should the API future look like (with some return value)?

```
static Future updateImage({sampleID, file}) async {...return val;}
```

Appreciate the help or in advance!

Comment: did you try https://pub.dev/packages/dio#sending-formdata
part with Sending FormData

Comment: Did not know about this but will try.

Comment: Solution is here: https://newcodingera.com/upload-images-to-rest-api-in-flutter/